# mustache and Internalviewresolvers - Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web, template-engine, mustache

I'm trying out mustache templates with spring mvc project. I've some code that is using JSPs and I would like to add mustache templating for some pages only. To do that, I added a new mustacheViewResolver and my existing InternalResourceViewResolver as below.

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
    InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/jsp/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    viewResolver.setOrder(2);
    return viewResolver;
}

@Bean
public ViewResolver mustacheViewResolver() {
    ScriptTemplateViewResolver viewResolver = new ScriptTemplateViewResolver();
    viewResolver.setPrefix("/static/templates/");
    viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    viewResolver.setOrder(1);
    return viewResolver;
}
```

Only either of them works but not both. When in intend to go to userform.jsp, it goes to userform.html.

```
[WARNING] /myproject/users/add
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [static/templates/users/userform.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateView.getTemplate(ScriptTemplateView.java:369)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.script.ScriptTemplateView.renderMergedOutputModel(ScriptTemplateView.java:349)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:303)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1243)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1027)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:971)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:969)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:860)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:845)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:808)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:587)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Any clues on how to use templating and JSP viewresolvers at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ScriptTemplateView` is not properly checking if the template file is available, which it should according to its Javadoc. This is a bug - check [SPR-14729](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-14729).

Please upgrade to the relevant Spring version.

Note that you should also keep your view resolver ordering like this, because unlike other templating engines, `InternalResourceViewResolver` and JSPs can't check for template existence and indeed throw exceptions, which is why they're often configured at the end of the chain.

Comment: So you tested against the latest snapshot versions? Those should be release tomorrow.

Comment: No I didn't test in all versions listed in Jira. I tested on 4.3.3.BUILD-SNAPSHOT version only.

Comment: Thanks for trying this snapshot version! Judging from the exception you were probably on 4.2.x - the next 4.2 version will also ship with a fix. Of course, upgrading to 4.3 is a good idea.

Comment: Yes. I was using 4.2.4.RELEASE. Thanks for the fix and prompt response.

Answer (score 0):

Since `InternalResourceViewResolver` implements `ViewResolver` up the hierarchy, you need to return `ScriptTemplateViewResolver` from the second resolver to let spring know that both are different resolvers.